# Shared class for another class and its parent in C++

Tags: c++

I need an access to some shared class from another class (DerivedClass) and its parent (BaseClass). Here's my idea:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual SharedClass *sharedClass; // Error! Virtual cannot use for non-static vars
    void callFromBaseClass() {
        sharedClass.testFunc(); 
        // I need an access to sharedClass here too as well as in the DerivedClass
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    SharedClass *sharedClass;
    DerivedClass( SharedClass *sharedClass ) {
        this->sharedClass = sharedClass;
    }
    void callFromDerivedClass() {
        sharedClass.testFunc();
    }
};
```

And using it:

```
SharedClass sharedClass;
DerivedClass derivedClass( &sharedClass );
```

I thought that I can use virtual for a pointer to a class but I get error there: **'virtual' can only appear on non-static member functions.**
So I don't know how to get an access to functions of sharedClass. Have you any ideas?

Comment: `sharedClass.testFunc()` should be `sharedClass->testFunc();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `virtual` is used to allow derived classes to provide their own implementation of a given function.

You are looking for basic inheritance of the data. This is always done and access is controlled with the visibility modifiers. You used `public:` (visible for everyone) but there also is `proctected:` (only visible to the class and it's subclasses) and `private:`.

Any normal variable in a class can be used by others if it is visible by that other class. In the other class the object declaration should not be repeated (because it will hide the one you are looking for by having the same name).

So in your case if you remove the declaration from the `DerivedClass` class you will be able to use the declaration in the `BaseClass`.

Resulting in the following:

```
class BaseClass {
protected:
    SharedClass *sharedClass; // No virtual
public:
    BaseClass( SharedClass *sharedClass ) {
        this->sharedClass = sharedClass;
    }
    void callFromBaseClass() {
        sharedClass->testFunc(); 
        // I need an access to sharedClass here too as well as in the DerivedClass
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    // No declaration of sharedClass
    DerivedClass( SharedClass *sharedClass )
          :BaseClass(sharedClass)   // Pass the shared class to the base class.
    {

    }
    void callFromDerivedClass() {
        // Shared class is visible here because it is in the base class with visibility protected.
        sharedClass->testFunc();
    }
};
```

Note that this will work when the variable is public, but it is best to limit the scope as much as you can, so protected is more sutable here.

Answer (score 2):

SharedClass *sharedClass; in the base class with public visibility is enough to call Shared class methods from Base class and Derived

Comment: You mean if I'll remove "virtual" keyword then sharedClass in the BaseClass will not be NULL without its initialization in the BaseClass? I think callFromBaseClass() will fail because sharedClass points to NULL.

Comment: first, some where in your code you have : Shared * obj=new SharedClass();  then you can call new DerivedClass(obj) ... in the Derived constructor you assign this->sharedClass = sharedClass;

Comment: you have to remove the the SharedClass*sharedClass declaration in Derived as you already have declared it in BaseClass